# How does the Fibonacci exponentiation by squaring algorithm work?

Tags: algorithms

This is one of the best algorithms to calculate the nth Fibonacci sequence. It only needs O(log(n)) time to do its job, so it's very efficient. I found it somewhere but don't know how it works!
Can anyone tell me how this algorithm works?

```c
int fib3 (int n) {
    int i = 1, j = 0, k = 0, h = 1, t;
    while (n > 0) {
        if (n % 2) {
            t = j * h;
            j = i * h + j * k + t;
            i = i * k + t;
        }
        t = h * h;
        h = 2 * k * h + t;
        k = k * k + t;
        n /= 2;
    }
    return j;
}
```

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring, and http://nayuki.eigenstate.org/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms under the `Matrix exponentiation (medium)` heading.

Comment: Thanks @RobertHarvey, I saw that link but I didn't understand. Could you please tell me what exactly it does? step-by-step. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Well, the code probably corresponds to the math.  You don't understand the math?

Comment: No I understand math. I just can't relate the formula to this code. and I don't know if I've got the formula matching exactly this code! @RobertHarvey

Answer (score 4):

It's called the "matrix form" - take a look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form)

You can compute next Fibonacci number (k+2) by multiplying matrix on a vector of two previous elements (k + 1 and k). Hence, k + 3 can be computed by multiplying matrix on vector of (k + 2 and k + 1). This equals squared matrix multiplied on (k + 1 and k). So on.

Your code simply squares the matrix, taking into account odd powers.

Comment: A true matrix form would require 12 variables. This is a variation of a Lucas sequence, which takes 5 variables (as seen in the question).

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but an explanation for how this works:

The algorithm is based on Lucas sequence relations for Fibonacci numbers.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_sequence#Other_relations

Specifically these equations:

```
F(m)   = F(m-1) + F(m-2)
F(m+n) = F(m+1) F(n) + F(m) F(n-1)
F(2n)  = F(n) L(n) = F(n) (F(n+1) + F(n-1))
       = F(n)((F(n) + F(n-1)) + F(n-1))
       = F(n) F(n) + 2 F(n) F(n-1)
```

Initial state:

```
i = F(-1) = 1
j = F( 0) = 0
k = F( 0) = 0
h = F( 1) = 1
```

n is treated as the sum of powers of 2: 2^a + 2^b + ... 
for each iteration *e*, let p = 2^i, then

```
h = F(p)
k = F(p-1)
```

To advance to the next iteration, h and k are advanced to F(next power of 2):

```
h' = F(2p) = F(p) F(p+1) + F(p) F(p-1)
   = F(p)(F(p) + F(p-1)) + F(p) F(p-1)
   = F(p) F(p) + F(p) F(p-1) + F(p) F(p-1)
   = F(p) F(p) + 2 F(p) F(p-1)
   = h h + 2 h k

k' = F(2p-1) = F(p + (p-1)) = F(p+1) F(p-1) + F(p) F(p-2)
   = (F(p) + F(p-1)) F(p-1) + F(p) (F(p) - F(p-1))
   = F(p) F(p-1) + F(p-1) F(p-1) + F(p) F(p) - F(p) F(p-1)
   = F(p) F(p) + F(p-1) F(p-1)
   = h h + k k
```

During the calculation of i and j, let *c* = current cumulative sum of bits of n:

```
i = F(c-1)
j = F(c)
```

To update i and j for 1 bits in n corresponding to *p* = current power of 2:

```
i' = F((c-1)+p) = F(c) F(p) + F(c-1) F(p-1)
   = j h + i k

j' = F(c+p) = F(c+1) F(p) + F(c) F(p-1)
   = (F(c)+F(c-1)) F(p) + F(c) F(p-1)
   = F(c) F(p) + F(c-1) F(p) + F(c) F(p-1)
   = j h + i h + j k
```

Comment: This is a very good answer, but it's not a very good *Software Engineering* answer.  Probably just shows that the question was asked in the wrong place.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - it's a question about an algorithm, in this case. how it works (similarly to asking how it was derived, which is what my answer provides), and I see "related" questions about algorithms also in Software Engineering. I spend more time at SO than at SE, so I'm not that familiar with where questions belong at SE.